# PYTHON: Read a log file and parse through specific strings to assign values from log file to strings that were identified

Tags: python, for-loop, parsing

I am new to Stack Overflow and a very novice script writer. I am trying to write a Python script regarding reading log files and parsing through its data to find mean and standard deviation of the message size that is printed in the log. The log file is a repetition of 3 lines that looks like this:
[image: Message_Log]

So far, I assigned the logfile variable with the actual log file, initialized 2 arrays, read the log file, used a for loop to loop through each keep_phrases of each line and if that phrase is in that line I append the important array with the line variable in list format:

```
logfile = r"C:\Users\vangjeris.dhroso\Documents\Python_Sandbox\Message_log.txt"

important = []
keep_phrases = ["Writer", "bytes"]

with open(logfile) as f:
    f = f.readlines()

for line in f:
    for phrase in keep_phrases:
        if phrase in line:
            important.append(line.split())
            break
print(important)
```

I have done this because I don't need to read the third line in the sequence. Where I would like to go next is take that specific message name in the first line (GENERIC_INFO) which is the 8th index in the array and check the second line for the byte size which is the 6th index in the second line. Once I have got this number, I want to repeat the process (so probably another for loop) until I reach the end of the log file for every GENERIC_INFO message. The I can do some arithmetic and calculate the mean and standard deviation for the set of message sizes I have collected. Then I would do this for other message types as well. Any help here would be much appreciated as I am stuck here.

I haven't yet attempted to write the code to look for the byte size in the second line of the sequence in the log file. The idea is I want to identify what type of message it is in the first line and then look for the byte size in the second line and collect that data to find mean and standard deviation.

Comment: Please post the logfile text instead of an image. This makes it easier to use the text data for checking written code.

Comment: Check out in the Python documentation how to use the `re` module and visit regex101.com . Learn how to get a slice of a list (`f[i:i+3]` will give you three lines out of f). With the regular expressions you can easily extract from the lines what you need and using slicing you can loop taking three lines at a time in one iteration what will make it easy to process all data within one iteration of a loop taking each time three lines of the log file.

Comment: Consider to use a Python dictionary storing in a key the kind of the message building in the value a list storing the amount of bytes. Getting this dictionary filled with values from the log file you can then very easy do and output the calculations processing the dictionary items (i.e. key, value pairs).